# Don't reload useCallback passed in parameter of child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

With React Native, In a `useCallback`, I have some very complicated calculations that I don't want to do multiple times. I have to pass this `useCallback` in a child component. But every time the child component is changed (by a state), then everything inside `useCallback` is re-executed.

Is it possible to prevent this?

Simplified example:

Parent :

```
...

const IndexScreen = () => {
  const tacTest = useCallback(
    (printedText) => {
      console.log('printedText')

      return (
        <Text>
          {printedText}
        </Text>
      )
    },
    [],
  )

  return (
      <TestScreen
        tacTest={tacTest}
      />
  )
```

This is my child component :

```
const TestScreen = ({ tacTest }) => {
  const [i, setI] = useState(0)

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {i}
      </Text>
      {tacTest('This is my second text')}
      <Button
        title="Press"
        onPress={() => setI(i + 1)} // Problem : every press reload tactTest useCallback and print console.log('printedText') again
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to save result of function you need `useMemo` in the child component rather  than `useCallback` in the parent:

```
 const TestScreen = ({ tacTest }) => {
      const [i, setI] = useState(0);
      const text = useMemo(()=>tacTest('This is my second text'), []);

      return (<View>
           {text}
      </View>)
 }
```